# Windows explorer right click crash

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer, right-click

Whenever i try to right click anywhere on windows explorer it stops responding.

OS - Windows vista

Thanks for any help!

EDIT - Only crashes when i right click on a file, not empty space.

Comment: Could be a malfunctioning shell extension that provides a context menu entry.

Comment: This's usually caused by 3rd party shell extensions. Try ShellExView - [Using ShellExView to Determine the Problematic Extension](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/slowrightclick.htm) should help.

Comment: @w32sh Yeah will try that. Thanks!

Comment: capture a crash dump and share it (Onedrive, dropbox link). Here Are the steps to do this: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Comment: have you created the dump?

Answer (score 0):

May be a third application that crashs or something bad in the register. When you "right click", context menu is created.

Try restarting your PC and boot in "safe mode". Then start your latest installed or updated apps.

Comment: The latest program i installed was lightroom and it has been fine since then. Or will it be since i executed a program for the first time today that i had sitting around for ages?

Comment: Also you can go to the windows registry to see what programs are in the "right click" or "explorer context menu". Did you try "safe mode"?

Comment: Not yet tryed safe mode because im flashing to a sd card but i will do. Also how would i see what applications are under the right click in windows registery?